# Retaining an autoreleased object is causing memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am collecting response into the variable

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)getCombineIdAndNames{    

NSMutableDictionary *lObjCombineIdAndNamesArrayPtr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

   [lObjCombineIdAndNamesArrayPtr setObject:lObjtempNamePtr 
                                       forKey:lObjtempIdPtr];
   return [lObjCombineIdAndNamesArrayPtr autorelease];
}
```

This is causing memory leak

```
gObjAppDelegatePtr.m_cObjCombineIdNameDictPtr = [gObjAppDelegatePtr.m_cDbHandler getCombineIdAndNames];
```

`gObjAppDelegatePtr.m_cObjCombineIdNameDictPtr`. That is a property of type copy. But it still giving memory leak. How to fix it.Please help me.

Comment: Could you tell us what is leak saying at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getCombineIdAndNames` is perfectly fine. You are `alloc`ing the dictionary and autoreleasing it before you return. Nothing wrong there.

This would suggest to me that the memory leak is being caused by the `gObjAppDelegatePtr` instance. Either it isn't releasing its property or maybe the whole object is being leaked.

As an aside, one thing you could improve in `getCombineIdAndNames` is to use the convenience constructor of  `NSMutableDictionary` to avoid all alloc/release calls completely. You can also use the new Obj-C container syntax:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)getCombineIdAndNames{    
    NSMutableDictionary *lObjCombineIdAndNamesArrayPtr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    lObjCombineIdAndNamesArrayPtr[lObjtempIdPtr] = lObjtempNamePtr;
    return lObjCombineIdAndNamesArrayPtr;
}
```

Comment: Still memory leak is there.I am not allocating the appdelegate dictionary as i am assigning a dictionary to appdelegate dictionary and it is property of type copy.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *lObjTempDictPtr = (NSMutableDictionary *)nil;                                                   lObjTempDictPtr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];lObjTempDictPtr = [[gObjAppDelegatePtr.m_cDbHandler getCombineIdAndNames]retain];gObjAppDelegatePtr.m_cObjCombineIdNameDictPtr = lObjTempDictPtr;SAFE_RELEASE(lObjTempDictPtr)
But it is still showing memory leak at the statement  lObjTempDictPtr = [[gObjAppDelegatePtr.m_cDbHandler getCombineIdAndNames] retain];

Comment: Still Memory leak is there at this place    gObjAppDelegatePtr.m_cObjCombineIdNameDictPtr = [gObjAppDelegatePtr.m_cDbHandler getCombineIdAndNames];                Please help me in fixing this issue.. Hope I will get help